# How to return output as a dictionary with unique key and multiple values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have below function where I am expecting the return as a dictionary with key and having multiple values.what is wrong in below code?

```
def get_list_animals():
        output = {}
        animal_house = ['ZOO','JUNGLE']
        connection = Connection("WORLD")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        for house in animal_house:
            statement = """select animals from inventory where place = '{}'""".format(house.upper())
            cursor.execute(statement)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                values = str(row).strip('()')
                if house == 'ZOO' or 'JUNGLE':
                    output[house] = values
                    #print(output)
        return output
    
    answer = get_list_animals()
    print(answer)
```

Return value:

```
{'ZOO': 'GOAT', 'JUNGLE': 'HORSE'}
```

whereas I am getting lots of values for both ZOO & JUNGLE in below way if I print

```
ZOO:
    {'ZOO': 'BEAR'}
    {'ZOO': 'MONKEY'}
    {'ZOO': 'MULE'}
JUNGLE:
    {'ZOO': 'MULE', 'JUNGLE': 'TIGER'}
    {'ZOO': 'MULE', 'JUNGLE': 'ELEPHANT'}
    {'ZOO': 'MULE', 'JUNGLE': 'HORSE'}
```

I am expecting a single dictionary as a return

{'**ZOO**': 'BEAR','MONKEY','MULE','**JUNGLE**': 'TIGER','ELEPHANT','HORSE'}

Comment: A dictionary can only have one value associated with it - maybe you want to have an array as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want the value to be an array then. You can do so by changing some of your lines of code

```py
from collections import defaultdict

   output = defaultdict(list)
   
   ...

   if house == 'ZOO' or 'JUNGLE':
        output[house].append(values)
```

Result:

```
{'ZOO': ['BEAR','MONKEY','MULE'],'JUNGLE': ['TIGER','ELEPHANT','HORSE']}
```

It's not *exactly* what you wanted, but it's what is allowed by python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_list_animals():
        animal_house = ['ZOO','JUNGLE']

        # initialize values of the dictionary as lists 
        output = {i:[] for i in animal_house}

         ...
                # append to the list
                if house == 'ZOO' or 'JUNGLE':
                    output[house].append(values)
         ...
```